# Resource recommendation for SHM & Wave

Tags: waves, resource-recommendations, harmonic-oscillator

I am looking for good resources or books on Simple Harmonic Motion and Wave that doesn't require any prior knowledge of those topics. Books that consist    even the derivation of even the very basic equation would be nice.

Comment: what’s wrong with the treatment of standard 1st yr physics texts?

Comment: sorry, don't have access to them

Comment: Since it sounds as if you don't have access to a university library or similar, I would draw your attention in particular to the draft textbook chapters by David Morin (also mentioned in the linked previous question of which this is a duplicate). They are publicly available on his website, and I found them to be a wonderful resource when teaching college sophomores about wave phenomena: http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/book.html.